# Converting string into mathematical expression python

Tags: python, math, input

I want to make simple program that asks user what function (mathematical) he wants to see
and then program draws it with turtle. I have drawing done but user input is tricky, I am sure you can't do that in one line of code but how to convert the input (string) into something like `x * 10 + 30 - x`, that can be put in function call

Ex.:
`function(x, x * 10 + 30 - x)`

My code:

```
print("Give function you want to see, don't do '2x', do 'x * 2', after and before signs like '+ * /' do space, USE ONLY X AND NUMBERS")
print("Example: x * x + 10 - x * 2")
print("Give function you want: ")

functionS = input()


def drawNewThing(x, function):
    goto(x * 2, function)

for i in range(100):
    drawNewThing(i, functionS)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` to evaluate the expression, but make sure the `x` variable must be defined before evaluating the expression.

The `eval` will directly execute expression by keeping value of `x` in the expression.

try below code

```
def drawNewThing(x, function):
    function = eval(function)
    goto(x * 2, function)
```

Comment: This is assuming the user input is both valid AND safe. Using eval could be exploited by someone passing malicious code into input()